# Calculate column in SQL Server using dates

Tags: sql-server-2008, date

I have a calculated column which is updated when two other columns are updated and the formula for this column is

```
SELECT(datediff(day,'2012-11-01 18:15:00.000','2012-10-22 11:59:58.000'))
```

It works fine for all other dates but when the month changes, then I get a negative value. How can I make sure this does not happen and I get the correct integer value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, two options:

1. just make sure the **earlier** date is always the first in your list of dates for `DATEDIFF`

   ```
   SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '2012-11-01 18:15:00.000', '2012-10-22 11:59:58.000')
   ```

   This gives you a result of **-10** - this is because the first date in your list is the later date.

   If you use

   ```
   SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '2012-10-22 11:59:58.000', '2012-11-01 18:15:00.000')
   ```

   you get the result of **10** - since the first date in `DATEDIFF` is the earlier date.
2. just use `ABS` to get the absolute value (without the + or -):

   ```
   SELECT ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, '2012-11-01 18:15:00.000', '2012-10-22 11:59:58.000'))
   ```

   In that case, you **never** get a negative value.